# Pick the odd one out: 214, 350, 520, 738

Tags: mathematics, number-property, odd-one-out

I am preparing for an exam(NTSE), and I came across this puzzle(aptitude) in one of the quizzes. [book(study guide NTSE)](https://www.amazon.in/Study-Guide-NTSE-Class-2019-2020/dp/9313197847). The book's author is Arihant Experts.

The question is to Pick the 'odd one out' and there are four options given.

> 214, 350, 520, 738.

The correct answer is 214. Can somebody explain why that is?

Comment: You said this was in a book. What's the name of the book? What's the title of the quiz? If I wanted to look up this question myself, provide the information I would need to find it. 
See also [How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing): "For non-web-based citations, include the source to the best of your ability (title, author, page number, etc)."  In other words, like I said, provide as much attribution information as you have available to you.

Comment: @Rubio made changes as suggested.

Comment: Thanks. You're going to want to add the same type of attribution to your [other question](/q/121021) before it gets closed for failure to attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer could be:

> 350 - because it is the only number with an even digit sum.

Or it could be:

> 738 - because it's the only multiple of 3

Or any number of other possibilities.

But I think the most likely reason for the given answer is:

> All the others are of the form n^3+n.
>
>  350 = 7^3 + 7
>  520 = 8^3 + 8
>  738 = 9^3 + 9
>
>  And 214 is just shy of 222 = 6^3 + 6

Comment: Nice catch. You must be really smart IRL.

Answer (score 2):

214 is the only choice below 300.

What, that's not good enough?

> Oh, ok - more than likely it's the odd choice because it's the only number given that has only two factors, 2 and 107.  The other choices all have factors besides 2 and (n/2).  That's pretty flimsy, but there's not much else here to go on.